# How to improve accuracy of OpenCV matching results in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to configure OpenCV within Python 3.6 to match a character icon (pattern) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaUHK.png) with a box of characters [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUJa4.jpg). Nevertheless, the match is quite low, especially for shaded characters like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaUHK.png).

I tried to solve it by using not only matchTemplate, but also comparing histograms, nevertheless - result is still poor.

I did try using gray-scale, colors, matching just a center of picture (cropped face), matching whole picture... resizing pattern to have exact dimension as it would be in a box... all combinations... and still this is VERY random (see attached image of correlation results) [image: Correltion]

Thank you in advance for help!

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image
import os

box = Image.open("/Users/user/Desktop/dbz/my_box.jpeg")
box.thumbnail((592,1053))

#conditions for each match step
character_threshold = 0.6 #checks in box
hist_threshold = 0.3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image
import os

box = Image.open("/Users/user/Desktop/dbz/my_box.jpeg")
box.thumbnail((592,1053))

#conditions for each match step
character_threshold = 0.6
hist_threshold = 0.3

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/user/Desktop/dbz/img/Super/TEQ/"):
    for file in files:
        if not file.startswith("."):
            print("now "  + file)
            char = os.path.join(root, file)

            #Opens and generate character's icon
            character = Image.open(char)
            character.thumbnail((153,139))
            
            #Crops face from the character's icon and converts to grayscale CV object
            face = character.crop((22,22,94,94)) #size 72x72 with centered face (should be 22,22,94,94)
            face_array = np.array(face).astype(np.uint8)
            face_array_gray = cv.cvtColor(face_array, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            
            #Converts the character's icon to grayscale CV object
            character_array = np.array(character).astype(np.uint8)
            character_array_gray = cv.cvtColor(character_array, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

            #Converts box screen to grayscale CV object
            box_array = np.array(box).astype(np.uint8)
            box_array_gray = cv.cvtColor(box_array, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        
            #Check whether the face is in the box
            character_score = cv.matchTemplate(box_array[:,:,2],face_array[:,:,2],cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            if character_score.max() > character_threshold:
                ij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(character_score),character_score.shape)
                x, y = ij[::-1] #np returns lower-left coordinates, whilst PIL accepts upper, left,lower, right !!!
                w, h = face_array_gray.shape
                face.show()           

                found = box.crop((x,y,x+w,y+h)) #expand border to 25 pixels in each size (Best is  (x-20,y-5,x+w,y+h+20))
                #found.show() 

                #found_character = np.array(found_character).astype(np.uint8)
                #found_character = cv.cvtColor(found_character, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
                    
                found_array = np.array(found).astype(np.uint8)
                found_array_gray = cv.cvtColor(found_array, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
                    
                found_hist = cv.calcHist([found_array],[0,1,2],None,[8,8,8],[0,256,0,256,0,256])
                found_hist = cv.normalize(found_hist,found_hist).flatten()

                found_hist_gray = cv.calcHist([found_array_gray],[0],None,[8],[0,256])
                found_hist_gray = cv.normalize(found_hist_gray,found_hist_gray).flatten()

                face_hist = cv.calcHist([face_array],[0,1,2],None,[8,8,8],[0,256,0,256,0,256])
                face_hist = cv.normalize(face_hist,face_hist).flatten()

                face_hist_gray = cv.calcHist([face_array_gray],[0],None,[8],[0,256])
                face_hist_gray = cv.normalize(face_hist_gray,face_hist_gray).flatten()

                character_hist = cv.calcHist([character_array],[0,1,2],None,[8,8,8],[0,256,0,256,0,256])
                character_hist = cv.normalize(character_hist,character_hist).flatten()

                character_hist_gray = cv.calcHist([character_array_gray],[0],None,[8],[0,256])
                character_hist_gray = cv.normalize(character_hist_gray,character_hist_gray).flatten()

                hist_compare_result_CORREL = cv.compareHist(found_hist_gray, character_hist_gray,cv.HISTCMP_CORREL)
                #hist_compare_result_CHISQR = cv.compareHist(found_hist_gray, character_hist_gray,cv.HISTCMP_CHISQR)
                #hist_compare_result_INTERSECT = cv.compareHist(found_hist_gray, character_hist_gray,cv.HISTCMP_INTERSECT)
                #hist_compare_result_BHATTACHARYYA = cv.compareHist(found_hist_gray, character_hist_gray,cv.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA)

                if (hist_compare_result_CORREL+character_score.max()) > 1:
                    print(f"Found {file} with a score:\n match:{character_score.max()}\n hist_correl: {hist_compare_result_CORREL}\n SUM:{hist_compare_result_CORREL+character_score.max()}", file=open("/Users/user/Desktop/dbz/out.log","a+"))
```

(1)
[image: Cell]

(2)
[image: Box]

Comment: Have you tried multi scale template matching in color and with a mask from the alpha channel of your template? I note that your template image scale is larger than the icons in your larger image.

Comment: Hey, as you can see in the code I do resize template (character.thumbnail((153,139))) so its dimensions are nearly-exact to the those in the image. Moreover, I also tried to crop just "face" (character.crop((22,22,94,94)),  in a case the bottom-right star would interfere correct answer.

Multi-scale template matching? Didn't hear about it — I will search for it and check whether it's usable herein

Comment: Try using a mask from the alpha channel of the template in the template matching?

Comment: Ah... so to match by shape. Okey, though wouldn't alpha channel just return frame of each template?

Comment: The mask from the alpha channel tells matchTemplate where not to include pixels in the match. Otherwise you are matching with whatever is under the alpha channel and that might degrade your match scores so that all matches are similar. So you have to read the template so as to keep the alpha channel. Then extract the alpha channel as a mask image and extract the color layers without the alpha channel as the image to be matched.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll take a look and search for a way of an implementation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of masked template matching in Python/OpenCV.

Image:

[image]

Transparent Template:

[image]

Template with alpha removed:

[image]

Template alpha channel extracted as mask image:

[image]

i

```
mport cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('logo.png')

# read template with alpha
tmplt = cv2.imread('hat_alpha.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
hh, ww = tmplt.shape[:2]

# extract template mask as grayscale from alpha channel and make 3 channels
tmplt_mask = tmplt[:,:,3]
tmplt_mask = cv2.merge([tmplt_mask,tmplt_mask,tmplt_mask])

# extract templt2 without alpha channel from tmplt
tmplt2 = tmplt[:,:,0:3]

# do template matching
corrimg = cv2.matchTemplate(img,tmplt2,cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, mask=tmplt_mask)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(corrimg)
max_val_ncc = '{:.3f}'.format(max_val)
print("correlation match score: " + max_val_ncc)
xx = max_loc[0]
yy = max_loc[1]
print('xmatch =',xx,'ymatch =',yy)

# draw red bounding box to define match location
result = img.copy()
pt1 = (xx,yy)
pt2 = (xx+ww, yy+hh)
cv2.rectangle(result, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 1)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('template2', tmplt2)
cv2.imshow('template_mask', tmplt_mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('logo_hat_match2.png', result)
```

Match location on input:

[image]

Match Information:

```
correlation match score: 1.000
xmatch = 417 ymatch = 44
```

Without the mask, the large green area in the template would mismatch in the input and lower the match score dramatically.

Comment: Thanks! As you can see my pictures differ just in a character in the square box. Should I crop border and just use alpha match for the faces?

Comment: With a mask, the outside does not matter. Your biggest issue is the scale the transparent template to the same size as the icons in your image. You will not get a  perfect match because of the yellow star in each icon that is not in the template. But the mask should help. Or you can make your template more transparent to avoid matching against the star region.

Comment: I scaled it and, as I though, this is the mask obtained from my template [Mask](https://imgur.com/Mm6E35G). No chance it would be found within image, since such a border is everywhere

Comment: The mask shape does not contribute to the match. All it does it tells matchTemplate to match the template only where the mask is white and ignore all pixels in the template where the mask is black. Look at my example more carefully. The green part of the template would mismatch everywhere in the image. But it is ignored when using the mask.

Comment: Okey, now I understand. Nevertheless, the match for my example is very poor – 0.66, whilst templates not occurring in the image reaches over 0.85.

Comment: Your match is poor because you did not use a mask in your template matching and perhaps have not scaled the template adequately. What matching do you get when using the mask? As I said before, you won't get a perfect match even with the mask, because of the mismatch due to the yellow star in each icon.

Comment: I did used yours script, only subtituted with my files. Actually it is scaled properly using PILs thumbnail - I've been even measuring the dimensions.

Comment: Post your new code. Which icons match better than the proper one? Does it have the yellow star? Perhaps modify your mask to make the region where the yellow star shows in your icon to also be transparent.